# Getting skip non existing resourceDirectory issue while using properties maven plugin iterator plugin and resources plugin

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I am trying to use three maven plugin at a time but getting error while executing. My goal is to read each environment properties that will place under src folder like application-sit.properties .. etc.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test.config</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-poc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>config-poc</name>

    <build>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/config/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>iterator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>moving property file</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>iterator</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <items>
                                <item>sit</item>
                                <item>uat</item>
                            </items>
                            <pluginExecutors>
                                <pluginExecutor>
                                    <plugin>
                                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                                    </plugin>
                                    <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <files>
                                            <file>${project.basedir}/config/resources/environments/common.properties</file>
                                            <file>${project.basedir}/config/resources/environments/@item@.properties</file>
                                        </files>
                                    </configuration>
                                </pluginExecutor>
                                <pluginExecutor>
                                    <plugin>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <version>2.7</version>
                                    </plugin>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/config/${item}/</outputDirectory>
                                        <resources>
                                            <resource>
                                                <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
                                                <filtering>false</filtering>
                                                <include>*.properties</include>
                                            </resource>
                                        </resources>
                                    </configuration>
                                </pluginExecutor>
                            </pluginExecutors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Getting below error while executing looks like read property plugin is not generating application.properties inside target folder. Below is the snapshot of my project.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.test.config:config-poc >---------------------
[INFO] Building config-poc 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ config-poc ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- iterator-maven-plugin:0.5.1:iterator (moving property file) @ config-poc ---
[INFO] ------ (sit) org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0.0:read-project-properties
[INFO] ------ (sit) org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:copy-resources
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\eclipse\F\eclipse_workspace3\config-poc\target\classes
[INFO] ------ (uat) org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0.0:read-project-properties
[INFO] ------ (uat) org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:copy-resources
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\eclipse\F\eclipse_workspace3\config-poc\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ config-poc ---
[INFO] Installing C:\eclipse\F\eclipse_workspace3\config-poc\pom.xml to C:\Users\Abhishek\.m2\repository\com\test\config\config-poc\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\config-poc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.798 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-08-29T16:29:36+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please ... add errors as text, don't take a photo of your screen...

Comment: Here is my error

Comment: Where is your error? You have not edited the question.

Comment: @JFabianMeier Please find error log

Comment: Reformat the pom.xml; remove the empty lines etc. best would be an example project on github. Furthermore the question is why do you like to use the iterator-maven-plugin? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @khmarbaise- Reformatted pom.xml and also added logs. In my project I need to read different environment properties files like sit.properties,uat.properties etc and those properties should placed inside application.properties which is under template folder.

My goal is to copy application.properties and put inside targer/classes/${item} for each iteration like sit , uat. etc. But its not happening. I got stuck from last 3 days. Any help would really appreciated.

Comment: Github Url - https://github.com/Abhi03Chauhan/maven-poc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below pluginExecutor structure will solve your problem.

```
<pluginExecutor>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</plugin>
<goal>copy-resources</goal>
<configuration>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/${item}/</outputDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/config/resources/templates</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <include>application.properties</include>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</configuration>
```